# Checking if column contains a pattern or not?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

[image]

I'm writing a query to get fname from user_name_n column in following query I'm using pathindex to find space as `'% %'` passing that pathindex return value to left 
and it works fine but I've records with `,` also how can i write a query
that will also take care of `,`.

and some records like `Bellian` doesn't have `space or ,` but still i want them in fname
but it's not working with following query.

```
SELECT top 100 user_name_n,left(user_name_n,(patindex('% %',user_name_n)))
from SFCHA10_04_02_2012;
```

can anyone tell me how can i achieve the desired results.

Comment: Looks like the first name is after the comma (when there is a comma), but the first name is before the space (when there is a space).

Comment: @downvoter thank you for your generosity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select user_name_n,
       left(user_name_n,patindex('%[, ]%',user_name_n + ' ')-1)
From   SFCHA10_04_02_2012;
```

Note that you can use '%[, ]%' to search for a space or a comma.  Also note that I added a + ' ' to the second parameter.  This causes there to be a match even when the data does not contain a space.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP (100) user_name_n,
    SUBSTRING(
        user_name_n,
        COALESCE(CHARINDEX(',',user_name_n)+1,1), 
        COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ',user_name_n),0),255))
from SFCHA10_04_02_2012;
```

If you want the last name instead of the first name when there is a comma in the form `lname,fname` (not sure why this bizarre requirement), then:

```
SELECT TOP (100) user_name_n,
    SUBSTRING(user_name_n, 1, 
  COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',',user_name_n)-1,-1),
        NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ',user_name_n),0),255))
from SFCHA10_04_02_2012;
```

Comment: well it works with `' '` but doesn't with `,` it gives last name like for 33,34,35 it has return Carol,Ryan,Shannon where i want Brown,Wilkey.

Comment: You want the last name when there is a comma? Why? Aren't Carol, Ryan and Shannon the first names?

Comment: No fname only when comma but your query gives the last name when it contains `,`;

Comment: So you're saying Carol is the last name and Brown is the first name?

Answer (score 0):

so first you replace comas and dots to white space on a CTE
and the you cut the name from the beginning to the first occurrence of a space (or the whole length in case there are no spaces):

```
with aux_query as(
select 
replace(REPLACE(user_name_n,',',' '),'.',' ')  as name
from SFCHA10_04_02_2012
)
select SUBSTRING (name,1, case CHARINDEX(' ',name) when null then LEN(name) else LEN(name) end)
from aux_query
```

Comment: Diego.. are you able to at least write a few sentences explaining your motive? What's myTAble? What's mystring? Is the 'name' field in aux_query supposed to be the same as user_name_n?

Comment: thanks (again) James. I of course created a table to test and I called It mytable. When posting the answer I forgot to change the names back to the originals. Goo coment